# php operator truncates file name

Tags: php, file, audio

I have an mp3 filename i.e. 50-Don't-Lose-Your-Saltiness-No.mp3, which is displayed in an iframe as an mp3 link, which is supposed to play the mp3 audio, when the link is clicked.
But the the ' character is being read in php as a truncation, so the link is chopped from

```
 https://mywebsite.com/folder name/50-Don't-Lose-Your-Saltiness-No.mp3
```

to

```
https://mywebsite.com/folder name/50-Don
```

so then it cannot find the file and does not play the audio.

Comment: I suspect you're using `'` as the delimiter of the attribute string, so the `'` in the URL is terminating the string. Use `urlencode()` to encode special characters.

Comment: You can also put `"` around the attribute instead of `'`, then it won't be matched by the character in the URL.

Comment: Also look at the generated output and it will probably be more clear what happened.

Comment: This look slike the line that is the problem <td><a href='./$namehref'$favicon class='name'>$name</a></td it does not like "